# GremlinPipeline returns duplicate nodes when i use .both

Tags: java, gremlin, titan

I use Titan Graph Database (0.4.1 release). I have a directed graph and I am trying to find the neighbors of a node. I use the GremlinPipeLine with the following code:

```
GremlinPipeline<String, Vertex> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<String, Vertex>(vertex).both("similar");
```

I suppose that this is caused because if I have the following edge list of a directed graph

```
1   32
32  1
```

the above function return node 32 two times. Is there a way to filter this with the GremlinPipeline or should I do it manually?

P.S. any other way to find the neighbors of a node is also accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dedup` and map to do a sort of Gremlin `DISTINCT`-like equivalent query:

```
GremlinPipeline<String, Vertex> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<String, Vertex>(vertex).both("similar").dedup(new PipeFunction<Vertex,String>() {
  public String compute(Vertex vertex) {
    return vertex.id;
  }
}).back(1);
```

The last back returns you the same kind of result you should have with the `both` call.